# GeoScript change layer's projection

Tags: geoserver, wps, geoscript

I am using geoscript to reproject a layer in my geoserver.

I can use geoserver/catalog to access a layer's projection with no issue.

However, I can't change it. My code is like this:

```
var catalog = require("geoserver/catalog");
var Process = require("geoscript/process").Process;
var Layer = require("geoscript/layer").Layer;
var Projection = require("geoscript/proj").Projection;

exports.process = new Process({
  inputs: {
    sentence: {
      type: "String"
    }
  },
  outputs: {
    old: {
      type: "String"
    },
    neo: {
      type: "String"
    },
    temp: {
      type: "Boolean"
    }
  },
  run: function() {
    var namespace = catalog.namespaces[0].alias;
    var myPrj = Projection("EPSG:2008");
    var myLayer = catalog.getVectorLayer("test:counties");
    //catalog.getVectorLayer("test:counties").projection = myPrj;
    return {
      old: myLayer.projection,
      neo: myPrj,
      temp: myLayer.temporary
    };
  }
});
```

The code I commented line never works however wps doesn't tell me any error.

Do you know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this page](http://geoscript.org/tutorials/data-basic/) seems to indicate that you can't just change the value of the projection attribute to reproject a layer.

Try something like:

```
js> // transform the boundary to EPSG:4326
js> boundary.projection = "epsg:2877";
js> boundary = boundary.transform("epsg:4326");
<Polygon [[[-104.85448745942264, 39.660159265877176], [-104.854236940...>
```

Comment: Thank you iant! This is exactly what I am looking for. I used this method and got geojson of the geometries. However, I also need attributes of the geometries. Do you know any other geoscript module attach attributes to geometries?